# How do i encode all chars in a string

Tags: php, encoding

How do i encode all chars in a string.

Example :
A = %32 // Or something like that 
B = %33

I want to do this without hardcoding every char. And i also want to be able to decode it again.
Is there a php function for this?

Thanks.

Comment: PHP has a lot of functions to encrypt strings.  Choosing the right one depends on the application.  Are you encrypting names, passwords, credit card information?  This is an important consideration, as simple string encryption is not ideal for sensitive information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to do this, you could do it with `preg_replace_callback` quite easily:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/./', function($char) {
    return '%' . ord($char[0]);
}, 'this is probably an unnecessary step');
// %116%104%105%115%32%105%115%32%112%114%111%98%97%98%108%121%32%97%110%32%117%110%110%101%99%101%115%115%97%114%121%32%115%116%101%112
```

You could reverse it with the inverse, using `chr`:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/%[^%]*/', function($seq) {
    return chr(substr($seq[0], 1));
}, '%116%104%105%115');
// this
```

However, this is almost certainly unnecessary for whatever you're doing...

See:

- [`chr`](http://php.net/chr)
- [`ord`](http://php.net/ord)
- [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback)

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
urlencode($string);
urldecode($string);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: I think this just encodes the special chars not every char...?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just mean ord() and chr() ?